# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'validate_email'

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to execute the following code in `python pandas`.

```
from email_validator import validate_email
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import pandas as pd
file =r'sampe.csv'
df=pd.read_csv(file,usecols =['name','email','phone'])
print(df)
```

But it gives `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'validate_email'` error!

I tried `from validate_email import validate_email` also as many reference articles suggested.

I have installed python 3.7 and anaconda. 
Please, can someone, give me a tip to overcome this problem?

Comment: do `pip install email_validator`?

Comment: It worked! Thank you for the quick response and the answer that fits! I had do run the above command both in spider.py and cmd.

Answer (score 3):

try installing email validator using this:

```
conda install -c conda-forge email_validator
```

make sure you are using correct `conda` environment

Answer (score 2):

Please install validate_email package.

```
pip install validate_email
```

And please import it in the code.

```
import validate_email
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `validate_email` package.

```
pip install validate_email
```